# TeamCity Overtime for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity for a TFS Project.

In build steps, i have a step for execute a powershell file. But i have an overtime and i doesn't know why...

[image]

My script, it work perfectly when I click on.

```
Start-Process "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList '/I D:\business\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7fffd86cdf4edfe8\Setup\Setup\Express\DVD-5\DiskImages\DISK1\business Régie.msi'
```

and my config build step

[image]

**EDIT :**

After 2 hours, i have alawys overtime. Just for one command !
[image]

**EDIT 2 (TEST WITH POWERSHELL ONLY OPEN CMD):**

i had try to change my command in my powershell file for only open cmd just for testing :

```
Start-Process -Verb runas cmd
```

i have build success but cmd not open...

Answer (score 0):

The `overtime` might be due to various factor.
It is based on the average time of your build.

- Case 1

If you ran this build, without this build step previously, the average time might be lesser than the current timer.

- Case 2

There might be real issue, where your current agent encountered several problems.

- Case 3

If you have heterogenous agents, the `rank` of your agents might not be the same, and performances to execute simple tasks may vary.

The overtime is not specific to PowerShell Build steps.

If the build agent is your developpement machine, the overtime might be due to background process on your computer.

You should not be worried for a delay of 90 seconds.

Comment: thanks dude for you replay, but after two hours isn't possible. When i'm trying to execute my ps1 file, it work directly

Comment: When you are running the script under teamcity, you might see the error inside the build logs. The error might be due to the ExecutionPolicy (`See Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`) 
Try running the powershell with the same command as TeamCity with powershell -Version 5.0 -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File DeploymentDev.ps1
It is possible that you have an error with the -NonInteractive parameter.

Comment: i don't think so, because if i'm using simple command line with : start calc.exe it is success but not display. i think the problem is more general

Comment: Also, i have only le v1.0 powershell on windows server 2012

Comment: I have install TeamCity on the second disk, not on the same OS